# Get latest message in a chat application - Django

Tags: javascript, django, websocket, django-channels

I've coded a chat application with Django Channels and it's working fine. The only issue is getting the latest messages and displaying them when coming back to the chat app. This is resolved for the moment by adding a function that gets older messages (`old_messages()`) in the `chatSocket.onopen = function(e)` part of the js file. **The only problem now is: when user A refreshes the page of chat, the other user (user B) gets the older messages two times** (*since the connexion is closed and open for a second time by user A*). Any idea how to avoid this problem ?

Here is a part of js file :

```
var chatSocket = new ReconnectingWebSocket(
        'ws://' + window.location.host +
        '/ws/chat/' + discussion_slug + '/');

chatSocket.onopen = function(e) {
      console.log("open",e)
      old_messages();

    };

function old_messages() {
      chatSocket.send(JSON.stringify({'command': 'old_messages',
                                      'discussion_slug': discussion_slug }));

    };
```

In consumers.py:

```
def old_messages(self,data):

    discussion_slug = Discussion.objects.get(slug=data['discussion_slug'])
    last_msgs = discussion_slug.messages.all()[:15]
    content = {
        'command': 'old',
        'message': self.many_msg_to_json(last_msgs)
    }
    return content


async def receive(self, text_data):
    data = json.loads(text_data)

    content = self.commands[data['command']](self,data)

    await self.channel_layer.group_send(
        self.room_group_name,
        {
            'type': 'chat_message',
            'message': content
        }
    )
```

Thanks!

Comment: The connection from user B shouldn't be affected by user A refreshing his connection. Each client has a separate connection with the server. So I hardly think that is the reason B is getting the messages duplicated. May be some other reason

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried ModelName.objects.all().reverse()? The sorting will be latest first so you might not need old_messages().

If this doesn’t help, let me know. I’ll take a better look once I get on my pc

Comment: Unless I didn't really understood, that's what I do in the old_message in consumers.py. The problem is, once the connexion is open (so in chatSocket.open() in js file), I need to bring latests messages (hence the old_messages() function in js file).